# Under what circumstances will an app deletes Firebase Instance ID?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

[FirebaseInstanceIdService.class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService) clearly states that `onTokenRefresh()` will be called when:

- App deletes Instance ID
- App is restored on a new device
- User uninstalls/reinstall the app
- User clears app data

When and under what circumstances will an app deletes an instance ID? Is there a possibility of it happening while an app is still active (ongoing activity or service)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app deletes the Instance ID when you call  [`FirebaseInstanceId.deleteInstanceId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#deleteInstanceId()) in app:

> Resets Instance ID and revokes all tokens.

And yes, you can call this method while your app is active.

Comment: but if I'm under impression that I will never have to call it manually, will my app automatically call that function?

Comment: AFAIK, no. The function will not get called if you won't explicitly call it yourself.